# Mecury Bimetallic Thermostat?

Tags: wiring

How many wires do I need to operate only the fan on my furnace with a mecury bimetallic thermostat?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two wires.  One wire (`R`) that comes from the transformer, and one (`G`) that powers the fan relay.

Answer (score 0):

A mercury thermostat is basically just a mercury tilt-switch on the end of a coil which moves/tilts it in response to temperature changes.

Typically it's used to open or close a low-voltage/low-current circuit, which operates a relay, which in turn operates the controlled load. That avoids any risk of the high-voltagge circuit being exposed at the thermostat.

NOTE that in many areas mercury is now considered a serious health hazard, and municipalities are encouraging folks to turn these in for safe disposal. Those programs may even include giving you a new electronic thermostat free or at a major discount. I'đ recommend you seriously consider that alternative.